# What to do with questions that were already solved?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

What to do with questions that have been solved by the user himself without any previous answers or comments?

For [example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111535/positioning-easy-fancybox).

Should these kind of questions be flagged or what?

Comment: It seems you've already solved this question by leaving a comment for the OP.

Comment: @Bart That's not recursive at all.

Comment: @Bart and what if the user never gives an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do any number of the following:

- Leave a comment asking the OP to post their answer as an answer
- Post the answer containing the content the OP provided (either in a comment or into the question itself).  Make sure to cite the author of that content appropriately.  Feel free to add to it if you want.  You can optionally mark the post as Community Wiki (this is a convention, but not a requirement) to indicate that the majority of the content is not your own.
- Post your own answer, without regard for the solution the author provided.

If the OP has stated *that* they found a solution, but not what it is, then you should simply leave a comment asking them to include that solution as an answer.  If you know the answer and want to post it, that is also appropriate.

Note that if the OP has edited an answer into the question itself it is appropriate to remove it from the question.  Answers belong in answers, not in the question.  If you do choose to remove it though, it's best to ensure that it's in an answer (either the OP's or yours) so that the content isn't *just* in the revision history.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and helpful explanation.