# What to do with a question that is answered in a chat room

Tags: discussion, chat, answers

On Stack Overflow I came to a solution through a chat room what is linked in the comments.
Related question: [Unable to resolve module `some-name` from `Path/To/Project/script.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791902/unable-to-resolve-module-some-name-from-path-to-project-script-js?noredirect=1#comment86607502_49791902)

I read: [What to do with questions that were already solved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194813/what-to-do-with-questions-that-were-already-solved)
And it is not clear to do for me what to do with my question.

Do I need to sort out the process of the chat and post that as a answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "sort out the process of the chat"?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The process of finding the solution.

Comment: I think he means if he need to "sort out" (=understand) the process that is described as a solution in the chat and then post said process as an answer on the question, referencing the chat messages that he used as a source. In which case the answer is probably "yes, fell free to extract the relevant info from the chat and post them as an answer"

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't post this on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions)? It is not forbidden to ask here if the question is appropriate across all sites in the SE network but you might be in for a surprise if you weren't aware of the two separate meta's and post something here that only flies on the site specific meta.

Comment: Yes because the chat room functionality is across all Stack Exchange sites. I posted the question as related because that is an example. For that matter, someone could have the same problem on a different SE site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, your answer came from a chat with someone who helped you get the answer. In that case, the best thing to do, would be to let the other person know that their contribution has solved your problem, and they can go ahead and post it as an answer. This way, they get the credit for helping.

If, for whatever reason, the other person doesn't want to post it as an answer, you can go ahead and post it yourself. In your post, you can add a thank you to the one that helped you get the answer.